# How can I repeat a program every x seconds for x seconds(in my case, every 3 seconds for 30 seconds)

Tags: python

My programming teacher had assigned me a simple task of creating a program that randomly generates a number between 1-100 every 3 seconds for 30 seconds. Here is my program so far:

```
import random
import time

while True:
    print(random.randint(0,100))
    time.sleep(3)
```

At the moment, it only prints every 3 seconds infinitely. I want it to repeat it for only 30 seconds.

Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: So keep track of time. You understand the concept of variable, right?

Comment: Instead of `while True` you need a loop construct that iterates 30/3 or 10 times right? That's every 3 seconds x 10 which totals 30 seconds. Or put another way, you'd have a "number of elapsed seconds" variable and you'd break out of the loop when it hits 30 seconds. The purpose of the assignment is for you to look at the Python documentation and determine how to iterate a fixed number of times.

Comment: And, pay attention to random.randint() and the requirements. Currently you are getting a random number between 0 and 100 with both included. Perhaps this is not a point of this assignment, but I would take points off for not following instructions if required range was "between 1-100".

Answer (score 3):

```
import random
import time
a=time.clock()

while ((time.clock()-a)<30):
    print(random.randint(0,100))
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Use time.time() instead. time.clock() can be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

It's an assignment, so we cannot solve it for you.  However, we can guide you to the correct module to use, that's `sched` documented here https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sched.html

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) function. It will give you the time in seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC).

```
import random
import time

counter = 30
start_time = time.time()
while time.time() - start_time < counter:
    print(random.randint(0,100))
    time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for range loop like so:

```
import time
import random
a=time.clock()
for x in range(10):
    print(random.randint(1,100))
    time.sleep(3)
```