# How can I write a loop to make the timer run every two seconds

Tags: python

I have a question on how I am able to set the timer so that every time it exits the loop it sets the time back to 2 seconds. The problem is that the first time the sound works after 2 seconds, the next times it is executed immediately. Thank you very much in advance for any advice.

This is my code:

```
            time = 2
            while time > 0:
                timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds=time)
                time -= 1
                duration = 1000
                freq = 440
            winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
```

Comment: What do you mean "the first time"? Is this all inside another loop? From what you've shown us, the beep is outside the loop, so it will only run once. (Also you've not shown anything being done with the `timer` variable you set; what's that for?) As shown, your `while` loop isn't actually dependant on real time, and would complete as fast as possible—much faster than two seconds.

Comment: In any event, this looks like a duplicate for what you ultimately want to do: [How can I repeat a program every x seconds for x seconds(in my case, every 3 seconds for 30 seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613619/how-can-i-repeat-a-program-every-x-seconds-for-x-secondsin-my-case-every-3-sec)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you meant that, but for me it seems like you just want to wait 2 seconds before executing the next steps. You can do that like so:

```py
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(2) # waits 2 seconds
    winsound.Beep(440, 1000)
```

Anyways I don't recommend you to use a plain infinite loop, without a break statement. Therefore I recommend you to add one, like down below.

```py
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(2) # waits 2 seconds
    winsound.Beep(440, 1000)

    if True: # break on a specific statment
        break
```

**Edit:** As CrazyChucky mentioned in the comments, this approach should work fine in most of the cases, but it can end up being more than two seconds sometimes. Therefore you should work with timedeltas or take a look at [scheduler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html).

Comment: This is fine in many cases, but keep in mind that this waits *at least* two seconds. It can end up being more sometimes, depending on what other processes your computer is running, so for more precision, one can check time deltas manually or use a [scheduler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html). (Also your example would be more complete if you wrapped those two lines in a `while True:` so it actually repeats.)

Answer (score 1):

To be more accurate as possible use:

```
import time

timer = 0
step = 2
t0 = time.time()
while True:
    timer = time.time() - t0
    wait = step - timer
    time.sleep(wait)
    print(time.time())
    winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
    t0 = time.time()
```

This script take in count the execution time of script lines for your computer.

Comment: Is this even necessary at all? `time.sleep(2)` would do the job. Correct me if I am wrong, since I haven't fully understand the question

Comment: If you wait 2 s, you will offset of the time of execution of one loop itération. This is the reason why you have to measure this execution time and substrat it. 10000 bips will be executed for exemple in 20001.568 s

Comment: I haven't used a loop since I thought that he just want to wait 2 seconds before the executes the function.

Comment: Sure, the question just looking for sleep function i think

Answer (score 0):

You just have to reinitialize the time at the end of the loop

```
time = 2
while True:
    timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds=time)
    time -= 1
    duration = 1000
    freq = 440
    if time == 0: 
        time = 2
        break
winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
```

Comment: You actually don't need the if-statement. Just reinitialize the time after the while loop

Comment: no. If is needed or else it will infinitely loop because of the while statment

Comment: It can't loop infinitely. While time is greater than 0 and in the while loop you subtract 1 from time each loop. So it will end after 2 loops.

Comment: This will in no way make anything dependant on two seconds of elapsed time, even if it were inside another loop. (But honestly, we don't know how the asker is calling this code; it must be inside another loop or function or something.)

Comment: @CrazyChucky Indeed, you absolutly right. I've just made a wild guess.

Comment: The problem is quite lacking in details. So I am just relying on this note "every time it exits the loop it sets the time back to 2 seconds". @MaikHasler The edit is noted, but I do prefer to put the reinitialization inside the while just to group it (honestly I'd put these in a function but I'm not sure how it will affect is code). I'll just edit it again if OP make his question more elucidating so we don't have to guess.

Comment: @KurtRojas Indeed, you are right. Of course it's not a mistake to reinitialize the variable within the loop. But please make a `while True:` loop then.

Comment: @MaikHasler Ah yes, I missed that. Thanks.